# Pipe out a substring by removing the last N characters

Tags: bash, unix

How can I pipe a string and drop a few characters off it?, e.g:

```
$ echo forbes | ... -3
for
$ echo cucumber | ... -4
cucu
$ echo 1461624333 | .. -3 
1461624
...
etc.
```

I couldn't find way to use `${str:0:-3}` syntax in a pipe.

Answer (score 20):

Piping to sed:

```
$ echo forbes | sed 's/...$//'
for
```

This matches the last three characters of the string and removes them (substitutes with the empty string).

To parametrize the number of characters to remove, we can wrap this in a little function:

```
pipesubstr () {
    sed "s/.\{$1\}$//"
}
```

to be used as follows:

```
$ echo forbes | pipesubstr 3
for
$ echo cucumber | pipesubstr 4
cucu
$ echo 1461624333 | pipesubstr 3
1461624
```

Answer (score 11):

**GNU `head`** is another option (remove the last N characters from the input string *as a whole* - even if it spans multiple lines):

```
# GNU `head` only (doesn't work with the `head` that comes with macOS)
# CAVEAT: -c operates on *bytes*, not characters.
$ printf '1461624333' | head -c -3   # drop last 3 chars.
1461624
```

Note that if you use `echo` instead of `printf`, there's a trailing `\n` that must be taken into account, so you must add `1` to the count (and the output won't have a trailing `\n`).

**Caveat:** `head -c`, despite what the short option name suggests, **operates on *bytes* rather than *characters***, and therefore only works robustly with single-byte encodings, such as ASCII and extended-ASCII variants (e.g., ISO-8859=1), and therefore *not* reliably with **UTF-8**: **only if the last N characters all happen to be ASCII-range characters** will the result be as expected.
Using the *long* form of the option  name, `--bytes`, makes this limitation more obvious.

---

As an aside:

- If you want to use GNU utilities on **macOS** too, you can install them via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):
  `brew install coreutils`
  This installs them with a `g` prefix by default (e.g. `ghead`), so as not to override the built-in utilities, but you can override the latter by   modifying your `PATH` as instructed in the instructions printed on installation.

Comment: @adius, yes, as the answer notes ("GNU `head` is another option"). However, I've added a source-code comment to spell out the macOS part explicitly, as well as instructions on how to install the GNU utilities on macOS.

Answer (score 9):

Use `cut`?

```
$ echo "forbes" | cut -b 1-3
for
```

**Update:**

To shave from behind, you can do:

```
echo "forbes" | rev | cut -c (n+1)- | rev
```

where `n` is number of characters you want to shave from end

```
echo "forbes" | rev | cut -c 4- | rev
for
```

Comment: it always returns first 3 chars, e.g. `echo kangaroo | cut -b 1-3`

Comment: thats what `-b 1-3` is supposed to tell `cut`. You start from 1 and tell how many characters you want.

Comment: that's the thing - I dunno how many characters in the string, I need to drop 3 last

Comment: Go with the other solution. That does what you want. Your question wasn't clear that you wanted to shave last 3 characters.

Comment: @Agzam Have added a way using `cut` and `rev` to shave from behind. But I would rather go with `sed` solution since it is much simpler.

Comment: ATTENTION: `n` starts with `1` (i.e. `cut -c '1-'` includes all characters!)

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution (removes the last `n` characters *from every line* in the input):

```
# Drop last 3 chars. from the (every) line.
$ echo '1461624333' | awk -v n=3 '{ print substr($0, 1, length($0)-n) }' 
1461624
```

**Caveat:** Not all `awk` implementations are locale-aware and therefore not all support **UTF-8**; for instance, BWK `awk` as found on macOS 14 (Sonoma) is *not*, while GNU `awk` (`gawk`) *is*:

```
$ echo 'usä' | awk -v n=1 '{ print substr($0, 1, length($0)-n) }'
us? # !! on macOS, mistakenly returns the first byte of multi-byte UTF8 char. 'ä'
```